# Adobe CF cfargument UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8, coldfusion

In a coldfusion component I have different functions in which I create a sql query and execute i. Code as follows:

```
<cffunction name="buildQuery" access="public" returntype="string">
  <cfargument name="json"               required="yes"          type="struct">
  <cfset blockStatements = "">
  <cfloop index="j" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(arguments.json.rows[arguments.json.columns[1]])#">   
    <cfscript>
        statement = "insert into " & arguments.json.tableName &" ("&ArrayToList(arguments.json.columns)&") values (";
        for (i=1;i LTE ArrayLen(arguments.json.columns);i=i+1) {
          value = transformValue(arguments.json.rows[arguments.json.columns[i]][j],arguments.json.tableInfo[arguments.json.columns[i]]); 
          <!--- transformValue just return my value formated, if requires '' o numeric without them--->
          if(Find('identity',arguments.json.tableInfo[arguments.json.columns[i]],0)){
            statement = Replace(statement, ","&arguments.json.columns[i], "" , "all");
          }
            <!--- here I remove all primary keys from the exported data--->
            statement = statement & value & ",";
          }
        }
        statement = statement & ");";
        statement = Replace(statement, ",);", ");" , "all");
        blockStatements = blockStatements & statement;
      </cfscript>
    </cfif>
  </cfloop>
  <cfif blockStatements neq "">
    <cfscript> executeQuery(blockStatements);<cfscript>
  </cfif>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="executeQuery" access="public" returntype="string">
  <cfargument name="query"  required="yes"      type="string">
  <cfdump var="#query#">
  <cfquery name="q_query" datasource="myDB">
    #Replace(query, "''", "'" , "all")#
  </cfquery>
</cffunction>
```

In `line 4`, before calling `executeQuery`, `queryString` have some special characters as (á,é,í,ó,ú). I have test the `query` directly on my `SQL DB` and works as spected, allowing me to have those special characters in a `varchar` column.

After calling `executeQuery` function, on `line 10` all those special characters have been replaced like `'í' -> 'Ã­-'`. Then, the function executes this 'new' query and `insert` in the DB.

How can I keep those special characters in the query when calling the function?
There should be a way to do it properly instead of `replace` them from the other side.

I have added a snipplet for the uploading form:

```js
function validate(form) {
  console.log(window.b = form);
}
```

```html
<form action="Importar_form.cfm" onsubmit="return validate(this);" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <cfoutput>Escoja un archivo: </cfoutput><br/> 
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" accept="text/plain, .txt"required>
  <br/><br/> 
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>
<cfif isdefined('form.FILETOUPLOAD')>
  <cftry>
    <cfscript>
      myfile = FileRead("#form.FILETOUPLOAD#"); 
      record=deserializeJSON(myfile);
    </cfscript>
  <cfcatch>
    <cfthrow message = "Archivo da&ntilde;ado, no se puede cargar.">
  </cfcatch>
  </cftry>
  <cfset componentPath = "myproject.Componentes.ImportData">
  <cfset componentOBJ = createObject("component","#componentPath#")>
  <cfset result = componentOBJ.buildQuery(
        json = "#record#"
      , method = "#form.method#"
  )>
  <script>
    alert("Se ha importado con &eeacute;xito");
  </script>
  </cfif>
```

The content of a file.txt to upload:

`{"tableName":"CRCParametros","tableInfo":{"Pcategoria":"varchar","Usucrea":"numeric","updatedat":"datetime","Pcodigo":"varchar","Pvalor":"varchar","TipoDato":"varchar","Mcodigo":"varchar","Pdescripcion":"varchar","createdat":"datetime","deletedat":"datetime","id":"intidentity","TipoParametro":"varchar","Parametros":"varchar","Usumodif":"numeric"},"keyColumnName":"Pcodigo","rows":{"Pcategoria":["Categoría"],"Usucrea":[24],"updatedat":[""],"Pcodigo":[30000601],"Pvalor":[10],"TipoDato":["E"],"Mcodigo":["CREDADM"],"Pdescripcion":["DiadeCorteQuincena1"],"createdat":["November,14201700:00:00"],"deletedat":[""],"id":[1],"TipoParametro":["R"],"Parametros":["1-15"],"Usumodif":[""]},"columns":["Pcategoria","Usucrea","updatedat","Pcodigo","Pvalor","TipoDato","Mcodigo","Pdescripcion","createdat","deletedat","id","TipoParametro","Parametros","Usumodif"]}`

literally ctrl+c, ctrl+v to the content. As you can see, the word '`Categoría`' in the json will be saved in the DB throught the query as '`CategorÃ­-a`'. But the DB support the character '`í`'.

Any explanation will gladly appreciate!

Comment: You could always try query parameters.  By the way, your replace function looks backwards.

Comment: What is the source of the characters in buildQuery()? Nothing related to the question, but `executeQuery()` is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: buildQuery() reads a plain text file that contains a json, the file is generated with utf-8 encoding allowing those characters, when read, those characters remain good til calling executeQuery(). Thanks for the observation! I'll fix it.

Comment: Update: I cannot reproduce it from what you have described. Can you post a small, self-contained example - including the test file content?  Just enough code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: What do you use to read the file into ColdFusion? What version of CF are you using? Which database? And _definitely_ watch out for injection. Validate everything.

Comment: I have test this code in my environment and works  "fine" allowing to reproduce de error. MicrosoftSQL2016 and CF9

Comment: @GiancarloBenítez - Thanks, but unfortunately the code doesn't compile. For tips, see http://www.sscce.org/.  1) Are the characters corrupted BEFORE the insert query or during? 2) If UTF8 support is needed, use type `nvarchar`, not `varchar`. 3) which database and CF version?